# Does one make a blessing on the scent of tea bags?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, smell

When I open a new box of tea bags, especially one that was sealed before I opened, I enjoy smelling the strong smell of the tea and/or various herbs that are in there.

**Does this require a *birkas hareiach* (blessing for smell)? If so, which?**

Comment: According to the Aruch Hashulchan, one should not to make a *birchath hareiach* except at *havdala*.

Comment: @Loewian in general, on any item?

Comment: @yitznewton I believe so. Though I also believe his is a minority opinion on this.

Answer (score 7):

Dinonline [answers](http://dinonline.org/2011/02/10/blessing-on-smelling-tea-leaves/):

> Yes, if one smells a herbal tea with the intention of enjoying its
>   scent, one should recite a berachah. If one takes the tea to drink it,
>   and only smells the scent by the way, one would not make a blessing.
>   Note that the scent of ordinary teas is not strong enough to warrant a
>   blessing upon “enjoying the scent,” and only if the tea is truly
>   fragrant would one recite a blessing.
>
> The blessing that one makes would be the appropriate blessing for the
>   herb, and hence would usually be borei isbei besamim.

Additionally, the sefer [Re'ach HaSadeh](https://books.google.com/books/about/Rei_ach_Hasadeh.html?id=dMgRAQAAIAAJ) (p.142) quotes Rav Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg saying:

> Common tea requires no blessing. However, some herbal teas are quite
>   fragrant, and the tea bag requires a blessing, according to its
>   source.

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting, I'm not on my computer right now---note: "The prevalent Minhag is to treat tea as a spice, and it is best to refrain from smelling it, and if it is smelled no Bracha is recited." Http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/2013/02/archives-hilchos-birchas-harayach.html?m=1

Comment: I'm undecided about accepting this answer. I'm sure Dinonline is run by great people; I just wish they would cite the seforim they used in answering the question :/

Comment: Agree with everything you noted - hopefully the new edit offers a little more of a source, although unfortunately the sefer doesn't appear to bring the source for tea either.